# Не работает функция сравнивание изображений

Tags: php, yii2

есть функция, которая сравнивает записи из базы с именем изображения (имена типа "123", "123_1","123_2" и т.п.) и сохраняет изображение, если такая запись существует :

```
public function matchImage()
{
    $this->image = UploadedFile::getInstances($this, 'image');
    if ($this->image && $this->validate()) {
        $barcodes = ProductsBarcodes::find()->all();
        foreach ($this->image as $image) {
            $origName = "$image->baseName";
            $exploded = explode("_", $origName);
            if (isset($exploded[1])) {
                $origName = $exploded[0];
            }
            foreach ($barcodes as $barcode) {
                if ($origName == $barcode->barcode) {
                    static::newImages($barcode->product_id, $image);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

проблема в том, что после того как функция проведет действия с именем, у которого есть разделитель ("123_1","123_2"), он не хочет обрабатывать следующее имя.
прим.:

```
array('123',
      '123_1',
      '123_2',
      '124' <= вот этот элемент не обрабатывается)
```

вообще у меня массив изображений, но я думаю что это не играет особой роли, ведь работаю я только с именем.

вопрос: я знаю, что  я накосячил, но где? какая то ошибка в алгоритме, но не могу понять где именно.

Comment: Вам нужно просто сравнить имена файлов и все?
Вы можете делать это с помощью регулярных выражений (в теории)

Comment: @АндрейДобровольский, имя файла с записью в базе данных. в любом случае у меня что-то не так с алгоритмом перебора. если вы видите что, то не могли бы вы подсказать, что именно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в ходе анализа выяснилось, что при использовании методов getInstances() класса UploadedFile можно загружать максимум 20 файлов, 21-ый просто вытесняется и не обрабатывается (даже если в правилах модели максимум больше).

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае ошибка кроется конкретно в проверки после использования функции **explode**, конкретно тут:

```
        $exploded = explode("_", $origName);
        if (isset($exploded[1])) {
            $origName = $exploded[0];
        }
```

Вы проверяете **isset($exploded[1])**, а ведь, если у нас строка вида "123", то вы просто игнорируете их, ведь в таком случае isset($exploded[1]) - вернет false.

И вообще, зачем вы проверяете именно наличие $exploded[1], ведь оригинальное имя файла содержится в $exploded[0]?

Оставьте просто:

```
    $origName =explode("_", $origName)[0];
```

Вот так:

```
public function matchImage()
{
   $this->image = UploadedFile::getInstances($this, 'image');
   if (!$this->image || !$this->validate()) {
    return false;
   }
   foreach ($this->image as $image) {
        $origName = explode('_', $image->baseName);

        foreach (ProductsBarcodes::find()->all() as $barcode) {
            if ($origName === $barcode->barcode) {
                static::newImages($barcode->product_id, $image);
                break;
            }
        }
   }
  return true;
 }
```

Comment: не помогло. однако, и хуже не стало.

Comment: $origName = "$image->baseName"; - вас это не смущает?

Comment: Вы не пишете имя файла, а $origName у вас равняется "$image->baseName"

Comment: суть в том, что я записываю название файла без расширения в переменную, потом разбиваю ее, и если она успешно разбилась (на 2 части), то делаю перезапись. видимо, можно сократить до                 `$exploded = explode("_", $image->baseName);
                $origName = $exploded[0];`, но ошибка кроется не в этом. и я не знал, что если нет разделителя, то explode будет создавать массив из одного элемента.

Comment: это просто рефакторинг, а нужно переработать цикл, т.к. в нем логическая ошибка, но я (изза тупости или невнимательности) ее не вижу.

Comment: выводите в цикле текущий $origName

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83669/discussion-between-dasauser-and--).